# MySQL match against string containing percentage char

Tags: mysql, against, match-against

I am trying to find the value in db row, that include percentage sign.

For example, there is a value of a row "reduced by 10%".

I need to filter results that have "10%" in them, not just "10".

I was trying to

```
SELECT name, MATCH(name) AGAINST('10\%') AS score 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

But it returned all the results with "10".

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%\%%' ORDER BY score DESC` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use MATCH AGAINST

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT name, MATCH(name) AGAINST('+10\%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: What's the result and what's your expectation?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I expect to filter results that have "10%" in them, not "10".
With your and my code I filtered all the results with "10"